# json_encode adding too many double quotes

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am working on a PHP web service that returns data in JSON form. I am at a point where I am now testing the web service with a jQuery/javascript file. It seems to be making the calls and receiving data correctly but the return values from the server seem to have too many double quotes.

PHP:

```
public static function getToken($username, $password)
        {
            $token = AuthenticationController::authenticate($username, $password);

            if ($token)
            {
                $user = AuthenticationController::getUserFromToken($token);

                if (UserController::userIsVerified($user->id))
                {
                    $t = array('token' => $token);

                    return json_encode($t);
                }

                return json_encode(array('error' => 'This account has not been verified. Check email and click the provided link to verify the account.'));
            }

            return json_encode(array('error' => 'Authentication failed.'));
        }
```

JS:

```
req.done(function(msg)
        {
            if (msg.error)
            {
                error = true;
                message = msg.error;
            }
            else if (msg.message)
            {
                message = msg.message;
            }
            else if (msg.token)
            {
                token = msg.token;
            }
            else 
            {
                error = true;
                message = "An unknown error has occured.";
            }
        });
```

For one, the `msg` object is not coming back as a JSON object but instead it comes in as a string, so I have to do a `$.parseJSON(msg)` on it. What you see below, the token variable ends up writing out to be  "mylongtoken" (quotes included). And if you look at that variable in firebug, it is like this: ""mylongtoken"". Is this just default behavior and I need to strip the quotes out?

Comment: are you telling the ajax function to expect a dataType: 'json' back from the server? if not, you'll have to parse the obj every time. If you're having too many "double quotes", is it an issue of the data you pull into the object? can we see the returned `string`?

Comment: Here is the raw string returned. "{"token":"mylongtoken"}" ... How do you tell $.post that you are expecting json?

Comment: From where you static getToken function called ??

Comment: I wrote a RestServer class (like PHP's native SoapServer) so I can make calls with jquery by url like: "http://myserver.com /api?method=getToken &username=name &password=pwd"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to enable jquery to parse your response as json, you must return an appropriate content type. `application/json` seems appropriate.

For added security, you can add `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` to prevent browsers that get tricked into reading your JSON as a normal page to try any content sniffing which might enable HTML parsing and XSS:

Second, If you get two sets of quotes, then something you coded does add them. json_encode() does not:

`echo json_encode(array('token' => 'tokenstring');` will output `{"token":"tokenstring"}` - no surrounding quotes. Any quotes inside any strings will be escaped using a backslash.

Comment: Thanks. I found that I was json_encode'ing twice somewhere in one of the classes.